# Algorithm for finding the smallest index difference of equal numbers in array

Tags: algorithm

Does anybody have any idea how to solve the next problem:

We have an array, for example let it be
a = {1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}.

What the algorithm should find is the size of the smallest difference between indices of the same numbers.
In this example (array a) difference of the indices of ones is 6-0=0 and 11-6=5, diff of the indices of zeroes is 5-1=4, diff of indices of minus ones is 4-2=2 and so on.
And the algorithm should return 2 because we can see it's the smallest diff of indices of the same numbers.

Is there any way to solve this problem in time complexity better than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several other answers propose sorting (element, index) pairs which can be done in O(n*logn). However, it is possible to do better, in just **O(n)** time. There is no need to sort the array, or to keep all the (element, index) pairs, as the minimum can be found greedily.

Loop through the array once and store the last index of each element in a hash.

```
int smallestDifference(int[] a) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> lastIndex = new HashMap<>();
    int minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (lastIndex.contains(a[i])) {
            minDiff = Math.min(minDiff, i - lastIndex.get(a[i]));
        }
        lastIndex.put(a[i], i);
    }
    return minDiff;
}
```

Insert/get from the hash is O(1) so that gives you O(n) for the whole array.

Comment: You should not trust everything they taught you in shool. Insert/get from the hash is not O(1) in reality. Try think about it a little bit. Do you think your hash access time will be same for 1T keys as for 1k keys? Really? It's very naive.

Comment: You are right that it's quite a feat from a hash library to pull off such a performance, but it is possible. However, a condescending tone rarely helps your case.

Comment: It's not my case, it's reality, deal with it. Hash was never O(1) and it is even worse today.

Comment: Care to provide evidence? Please expand your answer, then, why this approach would not work, providing some evidence.

Comment: Approach would work but definitely not O(N). It's always O(N log N) at best.

Comment: Second, hash itself doesn't have O(1) access time. For your key, you compute hash with a length of N bits. By this hash, you can make max 2^N buckets. For more keys you have to increase the number of buckets and you need more bits. You have to use slower hash with more bits. For 2^N buckets ~ keys you need a hash with N bits. You have O(logN) access time! O(1) is not true for an unlimited number of keys. O notation have sense only for unlimited number of keys. You don't have O(1) hash access time even for hypotetical O(1) memory which you even don't have in reality. So O(1) hash is nonsense.

Comment: First, you don't have memory with O(1) access time. Especially nowadays, you have all those CPU cache layers where an L1 cache is hundreds of times faster than main memory. It's three orders of magnitude. So let's ignore CPU caches even then you don't have O(1) memory access. Each memory has address decoder which must increase signal dept by one each time you doubles capacity. Yes, you now have in your computer some amount of memory with constant access but if you would like more capacity your access time will slow down with log N. So you don't have O(1) memory in reality.

Answer (score 2):

Make `vector<pair<int, int>>`, which would store original vector's values with their respective indices.  For each value v whose index is i, add (v,i) to the vector.

Sort the vector (by value then index).

Then go through sorted vector and find the smallest (or largest, if you want) distance between same valued elements.

This takes O(n log n) steps.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can add indexes to your sequence (O(N)):

```erlang
> L = [1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1].
[1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,1]
> LI = lists:zip(L, lists:seq(1, length(L))).
[{1,1},
 {0,2},
 {-1,3},
 {-2,4},
 {-1,5},
 {0,6},
 {1,7},
 {2,8},
 {3,9},
 {4,10},
 {5,11},
 {1,12}]
```

Then you sort it (O(N log N)):

```erlang
> LS = lists:sort(LI).
[{-2,4},
 {-1,3},
 {-1,5},
 {0,2},
 {0,6},
 {1,1},
 {1,7},
 {1,12},
 {2,8},
 {3,9},
 {4,10},
 {5,11}]
```

Then you find distances of all same values (O(N)):

```erlang
> LD = (fun F([{X, P1}|[{X,P2}|_]=T]) -> [{P2-P1, X, {P1, P2}} | F(T)]; F([_|T]) -> F(T); F([]) -> [] end)(LS).
[{2,-1,{3,5}},{4,0,{2,6}},{6,1,{1,7}},{5,1,{7,12}}]
```

Then you find minimal distance (O(N)):

```erlang
> lists:min(LD).
{2,-1,{3,5}}
```

It means minimal distance 2 of value -1 between positions 3 and 5 and result complexity is O(N log N). (Example code is in Erlang.)

Answer (score 0):

The following algo will work in `O(nlogn)`

```
 1) Make a map of <int,vector<int> > .
    2) Let the number be the key and the indexes be the vector.
    3) sort the vector for all the keys.
    4) Now find the minimum difference for all the difference between indices.
```

For example : For array `1 2 3 2 1 3`

```
1 -> [0,4]
2 ->[1,3]
3 -> [2,5]
```

Here we can see that 3-1 = 2 will give the minimum difference in indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in the Go programming language.

```
func smallestIndexDifference(numbers []int) (mindiff int, exists bool) {
  var prev map[int]int // The previous index where this number was found
  for i, number := range numbers {
    prevIndex, found := prev[number]
    if found {
      diff := i - prevDiff
      if !exists || diff < mindiff {
        exists, mindiff = true, diff
      }
    }
    prev[number] = i
  }
  return
}
```

This is completely untested, but if it works at all, it works in O(n log n).